# Lubuntu 17.10 multiple network icons

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10, icons, taskbar

I'm running Lubuntu 17.10.

Every time I login, there are two network manager icons, the location of the second varies. No GUI preferences solve it.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel` set

```
network=1
```

Comment: yes it should, typo thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution you've found yourself in order to help future readers :)